# Website page becomes narrow when www prefix is not typed in browser

Tags: php, firefox, rendering

This is one of the strangest things I have seen. In Firefox 3 for PC, pages for a website we are developing become squeezed narrow, which makes the layout go completely nuts.

If you type in http://www.wms-clients.com/vcb, the index page looks fine.

If you type in http://wms-clients.com/vcb, everything is squished.

Can anyone with FF3 for PC tell me if they are seeing the same thing, and if so, how I might go about fixing this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any difference -- using FF3.

Comment: It looks the same to me, on Safari 4.

Comment: Using FF3 on Windows XP, I see absolutely no difference.

Comment: FF3 on Mac here. No difference.

Comment: Thank you all for helping, the view needed to be reset of all things!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you been messing with the Text Zoom?  I believe zoom settings are stored per domain.

Try resetting the Zoom (View -> Zoom -> Reset)

Comment: That was it! Hot dog! Thanks Zoredache!

Comment: Fine bit of psychic debugging there, Andew! :-)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like it's caching files according to the URL.  Try "deleting private data", or press CTRL+F5 and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Are you on an internal network that is caching it at the server? Ours does that all the time.

They look identical to me. Are you messing with Firebug? It might be storing your changes to CSS. I'm on FF 3.0.6 with WinXP

Comment: No, not as far as I know. This is happening on the boss's computer, the only pc in the office using Firefox :(